Solving the Secretary Problem using Simple Math
In our computer coding class, we learned about the Secretary Problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem).
The goal of this problem is to find out the "optimal cutoff" for an interview process: What is the least number of candidates you need to interview that maximizes your chance of finding the best candidate?
If there are $n$ candidates (assume their skill level is randomly distributed) and you rank the first $1/e$ % of candidates (i.e 37%) and then pick the candidate better than the best of the $1/e$ set, there is a $1/e$% chance you will pick the best candidate in total.
We learned how to write a simulation for this:
library(ggplot2)
n <- 100
n_simulations <- 1000
first_set_size <- round(n / exp(1))
results <- data.frame(iteration = integer(), category = character(), candidate = integer())

for (i in 1:n_simulations) {
    candidates <- sample(1:n)
    first_set <- candidates[1:first_set_size]
    remaining_set <- candidates[(first_set_size + 1):n]
    
    best_in_first_set <- max(first_set)
    stopping_rule_candidate <- remaining_set[which.max(remaining_set > best_in_first_set)]
    
    results <- rbind(results, 
                     data.frame(iteration = i, category = "Best Candidate", candidate = n),
                     data.frame(iteration = i, category = "Best in First Set", candidate = best_in_first_set),
                     data.frame(iteration = i, category = "Stopping Rule Candidate", candidate = stopping_rule_candidate))
}


average_best_picked <- mean(results$candidate[results$category == "Stopping Rule Candidate"] == n)


ggplot(results, aes(x = iteration, y = candidate, color = category)) +
    geom_jitter(width = 0.3) +
    labs(x = "Iteration", y = "Candidate Number", 
         title = paste("Average times best candidate picked:", round(average_best_picked, 2)),
         colour = "Legend") +  # Change the legend title here
    scale_color_manual(values = c("Best Candidate" = "red", "Best in First Set" = "blue", "Stopping Rule Candidate" = "green")) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")


I am now trying to understand the mathematical solution to this problem but I am getting confused how to do this.
I came up with the following logic for $N$ candidates.

Suppose we have an integer number line from $0$ to $N$ that looks like this: $$[(0,R) , (R+1, N)]$$

If we find the 2nd best candidate between $(0,R)$, we are guaranteed to find the best candidate between $(R,N)$.

Condition 1: Relative to the entire set of candidates, the probability of finding the 2nd best candidate between $(0,R)$ is $\frac{R}{N}$

Condition 2: The probability of finding the overall best candidate between $(R+1, N)$ is $1 - \frac{R}{N}$. My logic is that $\frac{R}{N}$ is the probability of finding the overall best candidate in $R$ trials. So the probability of finding the overall best candidate outside of this set is $1 - \frac{R}{N}$

To find the overall best candidate according to the rules of this problem, both of these conditions have to be simultaneously true (i.e. multiply them by each other, joint probability)

Our goal is now to find out the optimal $R$. Let's call this optimal value as $R^*$. We can write a sum to express this as:


$$ P(R = R^*) = \sum_{R} \left[ \frac{R}{N} \cdot (1- \frac{R}{N} \right)] $$
However from here I am stuck. I think a derivative needs to be taken to find out which value of $R$ optimizes this equation. But I am not sure how to then prove that there will be a $1/e$ chance of finding the best candidate after reject the first $1/e$% of all candidates.
Any ideas what I can do?
PS: Our prof showed us a simulation which shows what happens when you try different "Stopping Rules" (we can see that they are all suboptimal compared to 1/e):
n <- 100
n_simulations <- 10000
results <- data.frame(stopping_rule = integer(), success_rate = numeric())

for (rule in 1:100) {
    success_count <- 0
    for (i in 1:n_simulations) {
        candidates <- sample(1:n)
        first_set_size <- round(n * rule / 100)
        first_set <- candidates[1:first_set_size]
        remaining_set <- candidates[(first_set_size + 1):n]
        
        best_in_first_set <- max(first_set)
        stopping_rule_candidate <- remaining_set[which.max(remaining_set > best_in_first_set)]
        
        if (!is.na(stopping_rule_candidate) && stopping_rule_candidate == n) {
            success_count <- success_count + 1
        }
    }
    success_rate <- success_count / n_simulations
    results <- rbind(results, data.frame(stopping_rule = rule, success_rate = success_rate))
}

best_rule <- results$stopping_rule[which.max(results$success_rate)]
best_rate <- max(results$success_rate)


results$color <- ifelse(results$stopping_rule == best_rule, "red", "black")

ggplot(results, aes(x = stopping_rule, y = success_rate, color = color)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_text(data = subset(results, stopping_rule == best_rule), 
              aes(label = paste("Best Rule: ", best_rule, "%")), 
              vjust = -1) +
    scale_color_identity() +
    labs(x = "Stopping Rule (%)", y = "Success Rate",
         title = paste("Success Rate of Different Stopping Rules\nBest Rule: ", best_rule, "% with Success Rate: ", round(best_rate, 2))) +
    theme_minimal()



In "Deriving the optimal policy" section of the Wikipedia page, you can see how $r^*\approx \frac1e \times n$ is theoretically obtained when $n$ is sufficiently large.
